# Request/Response of an Child class API in Parent Class

Tags: c#, inheritance, logging

I have many classes all inheriting from one base class. So I want to log the request (just the input parameters of the methods), the response (if there is one) and any exception (if there is one).

I can go ahead and modify all methods to do this and in future all methods need to implement this.

Or I was thinking if there is a way to log this info in the base class so that I can go and update only the base class and not the child class methods. I am not sure if it is possible to do it this way? If not, whats the best way to do something like this?

EDIT: This is a web application (MVC) and all controllers are inheriting from a base class and I need to log all action method hits (request, response, exception, etc)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `OnActionExecuting`, `OnActionExecuted`, and `OnException` in the base controller class?

Comment: I didn't. I was reading on those and I am not very sure how to implement those. Let's say I add those filters. How do I return the request, response, exception back to the base class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do this but it can become messy. Here is one implementation:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public void DoSomething(int one, int two, int three)
    {
        Log(string.Format("Method: DoSomething({0}, {1}, {2})", one, two, three));

        try
        {
            DoSomethingInternal(one, two, three);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(string.Format("Method: DoSomething Exception: " + ex.ToString()));
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public abstract void DoSomethingInternal(int one, int two, int three);
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void DoSomethingInternal(int one, int two, int three)
    {
        throw new Exception("I have no idea what to do");
    }
}
```

The methods actually live in the base class which calls an abstract method that the child classes implement. These can be wrapped in try/catches to catch any error that comes through. C#6 makes it easier with exception filters but I'll leave that up to you to decide to use.

Comment: This way we will have to implement that abstract method in each child class?

Comment: Yes, without using some kind of IL modification tool like Fody you are going to have to force a pattern here. Being that its marked abstract, it forces every child class to implement it.

Comment: Postsharp (https://www.postsharp.net/diagnostics/net-logging) also has features for logging like this, and is an IL modification tool.

Comment: What if these were controllers inheriting from a base class and we need to log all the requests/responses for the action methods? Would it be any different?

Comment: I think you are adding information that may be very important and should have been in your original post. Is this a web application? Are you wanting to intercept web requests and log the data before its passed on to the controller?

Comment: I am sorry but yes. This is a web application and I would like to log each api method request, response, exception. I will edit my original post to include this. Maybe we can add a custom Action Filter that we can decorate on all controllers?